# sshd binds to low numbered ports only if restarted with bash -x /etc/init.d/sshd restart

Tags: centos, ssh

I've added the line "Port 110" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config just bellow the existing line "Port 22" and then did an `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` expecting to see sshd listening on both ports (22 and 110). However netstat -anp showed that sshd was only listening to the default port (22).

Later I tried `bash -x /etc/init.d/sshd restart` and was amazed to see sshd bind to port 110 immediately!!! Issuing a second `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` again ignored my change. Rebooting also ignores my change so I'm stuck and utterly puzzled.

**UPDATE** this strange behaviour appears **only on low ports (<1024)**

This is on a CentOS 6 server.

---

**Details**

Here is my modification to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
grep ^Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Port 22
Port 110
```

Output of netstat after `bash -x /etc/init.d/sshd restart`

```
netstat -anp | grep -i listen|grep sshd|grep -v :::
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7031/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7031/sshd
```

Output of netstat after `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`

```
netstat -anp | grep -i listen|grep sshd|grep -v :::
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      8962/sshd
```

Another way to convince sshd to bind to port 110 is by running it in debug mode with `/usr/sbin/sshd -de`  (note the `listening on port 22,110` lines but I've also tested by connecting to both ports):

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -de
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.3p1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-de'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 110 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 110.
debug1: Bind to port 110 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 110.
```

Comment: Port 110 is the default port for POP3, are you sure there is no mailsystem running on the server as well that might try to claim the port simultaneously?

Comment: Yes absolutely sure. Note however that if anything like that was the problem bash -x would make zero difference. In fact it's crazy that it does make a very big difference in this case.

Comment: have you tried adding a 'set -x' to the top of the sshd init script to simulate the same effect and see if you get any more info?

Comment: Good idea Martin! But I tried it and it makes no difference!!! I only get the expected behaviour when I manually run the sshd script with bash -x!!!

Comment: Updated title and description to note that this strange behaviour appears only on low ports (<1024)

Comment: Is SELinux enabled?

Comment: You need root access to bind a service to ports < 1024. Are you getting error messages in `/var/log/messages` related to sshd`?

Comment: Ohhhh yes lain it is... Oh! boy Oh! boy so many wasted hours...

Comment: But hey! why on earth restarting with bash -x makes a damn difference to SELinux???

Comment: @Iain I verified that with SELinux disabled everything works as expected. From a security perspective though it is quite troubling that SELinux fails to restrict sshd's port binding options when I call its init script with bash -x. Any guess on where I should report this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SELinux system is restricting the port binding for ports below 1024

```
semanage port -l | grep ssh
ssh_port_t                     tcp      22
```

You can add another port

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 110
```

That would fix you immediate problem.

Comment: Thanks Iain! Any thoughts on why restarting with bash -x bypasses SELinux's restriction (which from a security perspective is quite troubling).

Comment: @ndemou the `-x` is a red herring it 'works' without it too. I've asked someone who is much more knowledgeable about it.

Comment: What a disappointment then, SELinux makes my life miserable WITHOUT succeeding in enforcing the rules... :(

Comment: If you run the init script directly, then the domain transitions to initrc_t and then further to sshd_t. If you call it from a bash subshell, the transition doesn't take place and it runs unconfined.

Comment: And if the above command fails with "semanage: Port tcp/110 already defined" you must use `semanage port -m -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 110` (see man semanage)